# Salesforce CPQ quote without opportunity

Tags: quote, cpq

We are currently using CPQ in our sales cloud and we've NOT enabled standard quote object.

We want to implementing service and field service cloud with an ability to generate quote for a case/work order.

SBQQ__Quote__c object has a required related lookup filter for opportunity.

From CPQ, We need to have the ability to add quote lines and generate quote document that can be mailed to the customer without opportunity.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible now.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_sales_cpq_orders_without_opp.htm

How: In Salesforce CPQ Orders package settings, select Create Orders Without Opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

`SBQQ__Quote__c.Opportunity__c` is not a required field in the schema and any required setting on the page layout can be removed.

[image]

Just because this is a managed package doesn't mean you can't edit the page layout

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I am referring to the related lookup filters section in the SBQQ__Quote__c  and I am unable to edit the filter type. Can you please confirm whether you can make edit at your instance [Filter]: https://www.screencast.com/t/JVJt7TdX, Edit: https://www.screencast.com/t/DkZO2mUOK1

Comment: I realized that the field is from Opportunity.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__c that has this filter required and unable to edit it.

Comment: @snathan - you are correct  = that field is not editable nor should it be as it belongs to a managed package - editing the behavior could cause the package to perform in unexpected ways

Comment: @snathan Were you able to use the Quote process w/o having the opportunity?